# sort nested list by int

Tags: python, list, nested

how do I sort the following nested list, I want to sort it by number:

```
highscorelist = [["erik", 2],["oskar", 5], ["markus", 3],["peter", 1]]
```

I want the list it to look like this:

```
sorted_highscorelist= [["peter", 1],["erik", 2],["markus", 3],["oskar", 5]]
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sort-list-according-second-element-sublist/ Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda function for this:

```
sorted(highscorelist, key = lambda x: x[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort it using the sorted method, and a lambda function.

Example:

```py
highscorelist = [["erik", 2],["oskar", 5], ["markus", 3],["peter", 1]]
sorted_highscorelist = sorted(highscorelist, key=lambda x: x[1])
```